# How do I filter out certain results based on the value of a faceted Attribute with Algolia Search for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, search, conditional-statements, filtering, algolia

I'm trying to filter out some results in an Algolia faceted search within Wordpress.  I want to show only certain results to a user logged in with a specific WP user role.  Here is what I have in my results now and it's not returning any result, but the pagination for the search does show up, so I know the script is running without errors.  I also do not have any console errors.

This is my current script from instantsearch.php:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-instantsearch-hit">
    <article itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

        <?php
        // Get data
        $post_title = '{{{ data._highlightResult.post_title.value }}}';
        $aim_of_work = '{{{ data._snippetResult.aim_of_organisations_work.value }}}';
        $organisation_region = '{{{ data._highlightResult.organisation_region.value }}}';
        ?>

        <?php 
        // If user is limited to Americas and the Carribbean
        if( in_array('americas', $user_info->roles) ) {

            if($organisation_region == 'Americas and the Caribbean') { ?>

                <!-- Print Americas Results -->
                <div class="ais-hits--content">
                    <h3 itemprop="name headline"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}" itemprop="url"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="ais-hits--tags">
                        <# for (var index in data.taxonomies.post_tag) { #>
                        <span class="ais-hits--tag">{{{ data._highlightResult.taxonomies.post_tag[index].value }}}</span>
                        <# } #>
                    </div>
                    <div class="excerpt">
                        <p>
                            <?php echo $aim_of_work; ?>...
                        </p>
                        <p class="text-small">Region: <?php echo $organisation_region; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ais-clearfix"></div>


            <?php } //END if

        } else { ?>

            <!-- Print All Results -->
            <div class="ais-hits--content">
                <h3 itemprop="name headline"><a href="{{ data.permalink }}" title="{{ data.post_title }}" itemprop="url"><?php echo $post_title; ?></a></h3>
                <div class="ais-hits--tags">
                    <# for (var index in data.taxonomies.post_tag) { #>
                    <span class="ais-hits--tag">{{{ data._highlightResult.taxonomies.post_tag[index].value }}}</span>
                    <# } #>
                </div>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $aim_of_work; ?>...
                    </p>
                    <p class="text-small">Region: <?php echo $organisation_region; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ais-clearfix"></div>

        <?php } // END if ?>
    </article>
</script>
```

My concern is that my conditional is not working: `if($organisation_region == 'Americas and the Caribbean')`

I feel like there is a better way to do this, but I would take any way that works right now.

/**-- UPDATE --*/
Here is my facet widget:

```
/* Region refinement widget */
search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.menu({
        container: '#facet-org-region',
        attributeName: 'organisation_region',
        sortBy: ['isRefined:desc', 'count:desc', 'name:asc'],
        limit: 10,
        templates: {
            header: '<h3 class="widgettitle">Region</h3>'
        }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to mix JavaScript code with PHP.

PHP code gets parsed and executed on the server side and JavaScript on the client side in the browser.

In your example, `$organisation_region` will always equal the string `'{{{ data._highlightResult.organisation_region.value }}}'`.

You probably want to add `organisation_region` as a facet and then refine on that.

To achieve that, you can take a look how other facets are implemented here https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/customize-search-page.html

Also, here is how to register your custom facet: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/indexing-settings.html#register-custom-facet

Comment: Thanks for your help, @rayrutjes.  I guess I was under the impression that this javascript was being executed on the server side with node.  I have looked at filtering facets and haven't been able to get anything to work.  Here is my current facet setup for organisation_region.  Any thoughts on how to refine this? `
search.addWidget(
 instantsearch.widgets.menu({
  container: '#facet-org-region',
  attributeName: 'organisation_region',
  sortBy: ['isRefined:desc', 'count:desc', 'name:asc'],
  limit: 10,
  templates: {
   header: '<h3 class="widgettitle">Region</h3>'
  }
 })
);`

Comment: I've added my current facet setup for organisation_region at the bottom of my original post.  Any thoughts on how to refine this for my needs?  I only want to return posts that contain "Americas and the Caribbean" as a value for "organisation_region"